# fail gitlab multijob pipeline if test job fails in another repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab ci pipeline in my application repo, A, which calls an end to end testing Repo T to run its tests. The repo A pipeline succesfully triggers the tests from Repo T but if the test job fails in T, the job calling the test job in T from A still passes. How do I get repo A to track the result of Repo T's test job, and pass/fail its pipeline based off of the test jobs in T?

.gitlab-ci.yml for testing Repo T:

```
stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  image: markhobson/maven-chrome:jdk-11
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/surefire-reports
  script:
    - mvn test
  only:
    - triggers
```

.gitlab-ci.yml from application repo A:

```
job1:
    stage: unit-tests ...
job2:
    stage: build ...
...

trigger-e2e-repo:
  stage: e2e-testing
  image: markhobson/maven-chrome
  script:
    - "curl -X POST -F token=repo-T-token -F ref=repo-T-branch https://repo-A/api/v4/projects/repo-T-id/trigger/pipeline"
  only:
    - repo-A-branch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GitLab 11.8 you can trigger a pipeline via [bridge job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html#triggering-a-downstream-pipeline-using-a-bridge-job).

> In GitLab 11.8, GitLab provides a new CI/CD configuration syntax to make this task easier, and avoid needing GitLab Runner for triggering cross-project pipelines.

With bridge jobs it is possible to [mirror the status of the trigger pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html#mirroring-status-from-triggered-pipeline) to the calling pipeline.

> You can mirror the pipeline status from the triggered pipeline to the source bridge job by using strategy: depend.

Example in your case:

```
trigger-e2e-repo:
  stage: e2e-testing
  trigger:
    project: repo-T
    strategy: depend
```

If the triggered pipeline with the test jobs fails, the calling pipeline also fails.

If you only want to execute a particular job in your repository "Repo T" when executed by a bridge job, then you should use `only: pipeline` ([only](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic)) or `rules: -if '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"'` ([rules:if](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#common-if-clauses-for-rules)) instead of `only: triggers`.

Comment: That's good to know. I'll mark it as the answer but I wasn't able to use this solution as my gitlab version is prior to 11.8. I did manage to hack a workaround which I will post below.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to use the bridge job property of mirroring a downstream job result as the version of my gitlab is before 11.8. I did manage to get it to work by creating a trigger for repo A, and making a call from repo T to repo A with this new second trigger. The remaining jobs in repo A will only be activated by triggers and setting of variables (`JOB` in this case ) as laid out below:

.gitlab-ci.yml for repo T:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn test
    - "curl -X POST -F token=repo-A-token -F ref=$BRANCH -F variables[JOB]=build https://project.com/api/v4/projects/project_id/trigger/pipeline"
```

.gitlab-ci.yml in A

```
job1:
  ...
  except:
    - triggers
job2:
  ...
  except:
    - triggers
...
trigger-e2e-repo:
  stage: e2e-testing
  script:
    - "curl -X POST -F token=repo-B-token -F ref=repo-B-branch -F variables[BRANCH]=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -F https://project-B/api/v4/projects/project-B-id/trigger/pipeline"
  except:
    - triggers

build_application_for_prod:
  stage: build_prod
  script:
    - "curl -X POST -F token=repo-A-token -F ref=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -F variables[JOB]=deploy -F variables[SEND]=true https://foo/api/v4/projects/proj_A_id/trigger/pipeline"
  only:
    variables:
      -  $JOB == "build"

deploy_production_environment:
  stage: deploy_prod
  script:
    - ...
  only:
    variables:
      - $JOB == "deploy"
```

Note I also had to add the `except` statements for the jobs before the end to end tests in repo A so that they won't rerun and loop when repo A's API trigger is called later on.